# Advice on an A-star script in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, a-star

I'm implementing A* in Unity so my NPCs can navigate through the world.
The nodes are Vector3s in the game, and they have a class called WaypointController on them.

Each waypoint has a list of adjacent nodes in the graph.
All my A* function needs to do is start at the closest node to the NPC that is within their line of sight, then do A* to the node within line of sight of where they're headed and closest.

I am pretty sure my A* finds the node with the lowest f score in the open set.
Then takes it out of open and puts it into the closed set.
Then breaks if current node is the destination.
Then looks at all nodes adjacent to the current node, and updates their f score and h score, and sets current node as the adjacent node's node before it.

Something is definitely wrong because it crashes unity when I call it.

...
public List GetPath(WaypointController start, WaypointController end)
{
List path = new List();

```
    //Don't interrupt other GetPath calls
    if (findingPath == false)
    {
        findingPath = true;

        //nodes to evaluate
        List<WaypointController> openNodes = new List<WaypointController>();
        //evaluated nodes
        List<WaypointController> closedNodes = new List<WaypointController>();

        //Setup start & end
        start.pathLengthToA = 0;
        start.distanceToZ = Vector3.Distance(start.transform.position, end.transform.position);
        end.distanceToZ = 0;

        //node being evaluated
        WaypointController currentNode = start;

        //Add start node  to open
        openNodes.Add(currentNode);

        //Evaluate nodes in the open set until currentNode = end
        do {
            //currentNode = lowest F cost node in openNodes
            foreach(WaypointController openWPC in openNodes)
            {
                if(openWPC.pathLengthToA + openWPC.distanceToZ < currentNode.pathLengthToA + currentNode.distanceToZ)
                {
                    Debug.Log("A* using: " + openWPC);
                    currentNode = openWPC;
                }
            }

            //Move currentNode from openNodes to closedNodes
            openNodes.Remove(currentNode);
            closedNodes.Add(currentNode);

            //Break if path complete
            if(currentNode == end)
                break;

            //For each adjacent node to currentNode
            float tempEdgeLength;
            foreach(WaypointController adjWPC in currentNode.adjacentNodes)
            {
                //Skip closed nodes
                if(closedNodes.Contains(adjWPC))
                    continue;

                //If new path to adjacent node is shorter, or adjacent node is not in open (set it up)
                graph.TryGetEdge(currentNode, adjWPC, out tempEdgeLength);
                if(currentNode.pathLengthToA + tempEdgeLength < adjWPC.pathLengthToA || openNodes.Contains(adjWPC) == false)
                {
                    Debug.Log("A* is evaluating node: " + adjWPC.name);

                    //set f cost of neighbor
                    adjWPC.pathLengthToA = currentNode.pathLengthToA + tempEdgeLength;
                    adjWPC.distanceToZ = Vector3.Distance(adjWPC.transform.position, end.transform.position);

                    //set nodeBeforeThisInPath in neighbor to currentNode
                    adjWPC.nodeBeforeThisInPath = currentNode;

                    //add neighbor to openNodes
                    if(openNodes.Contains(adjWPC) == false)
                        openNodes.Add(adjWPC);
                }
            }

        } while (currentNode != end);

        //Output it
        path.Add(start.transform.position);
        while (currentNode.nodeBeforeThisInPath != start)
        {
            path.Add(currentNode.nodeBeforeThisInPath.transform.position);
        }
        path.Add(end.transform.position);

        //free up the function
        findingPath = false;
    }
    else
    {
        path.Add(Vector3.zero);
    }

    //Return the path or an empty path if findingPath was already true (& handle retry in the other script
    return path;
}
```

...

Thanks for joining me on this puzzle.
I will post any updates as I discover them.

Comment: So put it in a coroutine. Wait at the end of each check and display a log. Make sure you don’t have collapse on so you see each line repeating not just a counter which will make it hard to check at the end. Watch. There will be an endless loop somewhere

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the crash, but you should be using proper data structures for the open/closed lists. I have a C# priority queue explicitly designed for path-finding [here](https://github.com/BlueRaja/High-Speed-Priority-Queue-for-C-Sharp)